# Про оправданную и неоправданную тавтологию

Tags: тавтология

"Дарить подарки" и "подарить подарки".

Собственно, вот и вопрос. Почему первое словосочетание звучит вполне нормально, а второе – ужасно?

Comment: StoneyB на форуме английского языка любит в подобных случаях упоминать "[принцип horror aequi](http://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=horror+aequi)" - нам не нравится, когда грамматические конструкции повторяют друг друга по форме (за исключением некоторых поэтических конструкций, наверное). Может быть, и в данном случае этот принцип действует: "**по**дарить" ближе по звучанию к "**по**дарки" благодаря наличию **по**.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте на вопрос в комментариях, это нужно делать в отдельном поле.

Comment: Почему первое словосочетание звучит вполне нормально?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что дело в резко различающейся потребности в одном и другом выражениях. "Подарить подарки" мы практически не слышим, поэтому оно воспринимается как тавтологичный неологизм. Тем не менее можно вообразить ситуацию, когда такое выражение не покажется диким: кинорежиссёр конкретизирует актёру предстоящие действия в кадре, мол, ему нужно "выйти из той двери, подойти к детям, подарить подарки (о которых они уже говорили) и скрыться". Это звучит нормально, поскольку "сделать подарки" не подходит из-за условности предполагаемого действия, а "нестандартность" применённого выражения легко списать на иронию или профессиональный жаргон.
Выражения же "**дарить подарки**" (абстрактное обозначение действия дарения неназванных предметов) и "**надарить подарков**" (ирония по поводу чьей-то щедрости или множественности дарящих) мы слышим в часто встречающихся ситуациях, как и "делать дело" ("сделать дело"). В конкретных ситуациях можно попросту назвать подаренное; кроме того, не всякий подарок можно "подарить" подобно вещи - отсюда распространённость выражения "сделать подарок", которое универсально.

Пример того, как отсутствие потребности в образовании слов и редкое использование заставляет их звучать странно. Пробудиться - пробуждение. А каково отглагольное существительное от "разбудить" (кого-то)? Вполне нормально образованного слова "разбуждение" мы не слышим из-за относительной его ненадобности. По этой причине возникает множество споров, как назвать появившуюся гостиничную услугу (в некоторых местах её так и назвали - по необходимости и без предрассудков). Между тем, есть забытый случай применения этого слова в названии одного из переведённых сочинений Вольтера (там фигурировало "разбуждение королей").

Answer (score 1):

В обоих случаях тавтология оправдана. Первая фраза звучит красивее, потому что она даёт ямбовый ритм (`_/ _/ _`), во втором же случае чёткого ритма нет (`__/ _/ _`). После смены ударения, например *подарит подарок*, фраза начинает звучать лучше.

Читал исследование, где авторы утверждали, что в непосредственной живой речи мы стремимся произносить фразы близко к стихотворным размерам, с нарушением в одной или двух стопах, причём "слова-паразиты" (вот, как бы, ну, и пр.) помогают этот размер соблюдать.

Comment: Я не читал этого исследования, но для меня эта точка зрения любопытна тем, что я на одном сайте в шутку высказывал похожее. Мол,  хорошие прозаики, как и сочинители белого стиха, вероятно, пользуются таким приёмом: пишут в рифму (от неё им трудно отмахнуться), а потом убивают её - в результате получается складно и легко обратимо снова в рифму. "В доказательство" зарифмовал финал пушкинской повести "Метель" и вспомнил случай, как по рассеянности перевёл в рифму фрагмент шекспировского "Юлия Цезаря", написанного белым стихом. В этом смысле, автор исследования льстит основной массе говорящих.

Comment: @Alex_ander я читал предварительные результаты. Суть исследования была в том, что к добровольцам прикреплялся на сутки диктофон и записывалось всё что они говорят. Так как большинство добровольцев были филологами, то тут скорее можно  говорить о неких образцах разговорной речи, нежели о статистической выборке.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что глагол *дарить* раскрывает смысл корня **дар**, заключенного в слове *подарки*, усиливает основное значение. А повторение приставки **по** производит видимость ненужного повтора действия. Что делать - дарить, что сделать - подарить. Глагол образован прибавлением приставки **по**. И существительное *подарок* образовано уже от этого глагола. Подарить то, что уже подарено. Так что ли получается?..